# Mono profiling: Perf syscall denied

Tags: ubuntu, mono

On a Ubuntu machine I tried to profile the CPU usage of a mono (3.2.8) application. According the manual, I can generate these samples by

```
mono --profile=log:sample MyApplication.exe
```

However I always get the following error messages, samples don't seem to be generated:

```
Perf syscall denied, do "echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid" as root to enable.
```

I changed the value of perf_event_paranoid accordingly, however the error remains. Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, you found a solution?